# C function that converts 4 bytes to integer in char array

Tags: arrays, c, bit-manipulation, bit

I am facing a bit of a dilemma.

I have a unsigned char array of size 2034 bytes, now in this array I wish to store integers of size 4 bytes

Meaning 2^32 bits

Now I understand that if I wanted to store the value 100000

I would need to spread out my bytes across 4 positions.

So this is what I have so far

```
void store_int(char* arr, int index, int value) {
    arr[index] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+3] = value & 0xFF;
}
```

Likewise I also  have made a function that takes an index, and access the 4 bytes spread across the array, to return a signed integer

Here it is

```
int read_int(const unsigned char* arr, int index) {
    int value = 0;
    value |= ((int)arr[index]) << 24;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+1]) << 16;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+2]) << 8;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+3]);
    return value;
}
```

Now I am stuck at this stage

I wish to create a function that takes an index, and returns the first 8 bits preserving the sign and returns it as an integer, how would I go about doing this

For example, if my integer is 500500, it is stored in a char array across 4 index positions,

For example 500500 in binary is :00000000000001111010001100010100

I wish to get the first byte or 8 bits

Which is 00010100 or 20, I also want to preserve the sign, is it okay, if someone can write a function, like this

I wish for two functions that return the first bit in big endian and little endian format so (index +3) and index

```
    int return_first_8_bits(unsigned char* array, int index){


     return 0;
     }
```

In addition to this, in my code store_int and read_int storing into my arr as little endian.

Comment: The first 8 bits are in `arr[index+3]`. `In addition to this, in my code store_int and read_int storing into my arr as little endian.` You store it as big endian.

Comment: And it's a lot less bug-prone to always use unsigned values of a specific size such as `uint32_t` when you need shift bytes of a specific size around.  `int` isn't always 32 bits and shifting signed values is troublesome in a lot of cases.

Comment: What should I do in that case?

Comment: How can I store it as little endian.

Comment: Store it the other way around. The lowest 8 bits in the _first_ byte.